# Maven appassembler-maven-plugin and Tanuki JSW using a version later than 3.2.3

Tags: java, maven, java-service-wrapper, yajsw, tanuki

I am using the [Tanuki](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp)  wrapper with the  [appassembler-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/usage_jsw.html)  and by default it seems to be using Tanuki 3.2.3

I want to use a later version of Tanuki but I can't see how to do it. There are some [discussions](https://www.mail-archive.com/user@mojo.codehaus.org/msg03120.html) that the appassembler-maven-plugin is stuck on 3.2.3 is this true?

[UPDATE]
Ok so from what I now understand. The appassembler-maven-plugin included the tanuki jsw source in the plugin which is why its stuck at 3.2.3 as the licencing changed after that version.

You can still use the appassembler plugin with a later version of Tanuki but you have to unpack the Tanuki distribution yourself. Tanuki JSW do not provide maven integration.